# Question about Daemon and Non-Daemon Threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to learn about Threads in Python. I know that when the `App Main Threat` exits the Daemon Threads are terminated too, but any Non-Daemon Thread executes till the end. So based on that, can anyone tell me why this code stops even when Thread D (a Non-Daemon Thread) is still executing?!

The output it gives on Thonny is:

```
Starting of thread : Thread A

Starting of thread : Thread B

Finishing of thread : Thread B

Finishing of thread : Thread A

Starting of thread : Thread C

Starting of thread : Thread D
```

My code:

```
import threading
import time


def a():
  print('Starting of thread :', threading.currentThread().name)
  time.sleep(10)
  print('Finishing of thread :', threading.currentThread().name)


def b():
  print('Starting of thread :', threading.currentThread().name)
  time.sleep(5)
  print('Finishing of thread :', threading.currentThread().name)


a = threading.Thread(name = "Thread A", target = a)
b = threading.Thread(name = "Thread B", target = b)
a.start()
b.start()


time.sleep(15)  # Just a pause between Threads A,B and C,D.


def c():
  print('Starting of thread :', threading.currentThread().name)
  time.sleep(10)
  print('Finishing of thread :', threading.currentThread().name)


def d():
  print('Starting of thread :', threading.currentThread().name)
  time.sleep(5)
  print('Finishing of thread :', threading.currentThread().name)


c = threading.Thread(name = "Thread C", target = c, daemon = True)
d = threading.Thread(name = "Thread D", target = d)
c.start()
d.start()

exit()
```

Comment: Could it be linked to maybe the interpreter used by Thonny? I've just ran your code on PyCharm (python 3.7 interpreter) and it ran without flaw. Allowing the non-Daemon thread to finish before exiting.

Comment: Yes Kelo, i had some suspicion about that, but i couldn't confirm. So i appreciate your confirmation. Thank you.

Comment: Your example does not show the usage of `daemon=True`, therefore you don't see any differences. Your threaded functions are all terminating by itself. You have to use `while True:`, no i can't explain why this is different from `.sleep(x)`. Run case 2 at [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/FormalFairCharmap) to see how `daemon=True` works.

Comment: stovfl, i tested the code above in repl and actually it worked, i'm using Thonny and i guess, like Kelo wrote, it messes a bit with the Threads when they have to shutdown, specially Thread C and D!